# AngularFire: how to "safely" add an item?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm trying to "safely" add an item to my Firebase "players" collection, i.e.: checking for remote errors (server down, link down, ...), to be able to notify users of the (temporary) failure of the requested add operation.

This is my current code:

```
app.factory('playersFactory',
  function($firebase, FIREBASE_URL) {
    var url = FIREBASE_URL + '/' + 'players';
    var ref = new Firebase(url);
    var players = $firebase(ref);

    return {
      add: function(player) {
        return players.$add(player).then(
          function (ref) {
            var id = ref.name();
            console.error('SUCCESS: added player with id:', id);
            return id;
          },
          function (err) {
            console.error('ERROR:', err);
            return null;
          }
        );
      }
      // ...
    }
  }
);
```

My questions are:

- is my code valid? (I didn't find any reference - my fault, for sure - about the suggested way to catch angularfire errors...).
- is my use of the second callback to `$add(player).then(` to catch errors is valid? I suppose it's not, since I tryed to simulate a failure unplugging network cable just before "add", and no ERROR was shown...
- is the effort to catch these errors with firebase a real need at all?

Answer (score 1):

This approach looks correct. $add is the ideal way to add items where you want them to be regurgitated in chronological order and have unique ids. Catching the errors should be done using then() as you've discovered.

Note that you won't generate an error just because you unplug a network cable. Firebase is fault-tolerant and will apply the changes locally, waiting for the connection to be restored before sending up to the server. You would be better off creating an error condition by setting a security rule that prevents write to the path in question.

```
 ".write": "!newData.child('shouldFail').exists()" // for example
```

You may also want to check out [MockFirebase](https://github.com/katowulf/mockfirebase). It's not complete in every regard, nor perfectly documented, but is used for testing AngularFire. Like other Angular mocks (such as $http), it works by using a flush() method to trigger the callbacks at your discretion, allowing you sophisticated control over when events fire, simulating async in a controllable manner. There is also a failNext method, which only works on set() at present, but would be a few minutes work to add to any other method you need to work with.

Comment: @ Kato: Thanks for your answer!
I did never dig into Firebase Security Rules... :-(
However I wasn't able to simulate a client $add failure, even setting that rule... (I got a regular "Success" in my firebug console, and effectively new data is in firebase...
These are my security rules:
 {
   "rules": {
     ".read": true,
     ".write": "!newData.child('shouldFail').exists()"
   }
 }
I only need a simple way and quick to test my logic in case of failures, so I'd better avoid digging with MockFirebase, for the moment...